# HTML Form POST/Save render value another page

Tags: html, post, django-forms

I have a post form I am enetering a value for. I would like to save the value in the form and timestamp it to save and render the information to another page. Any clean ways to do this?. I am using the DJANGO framework, so far I have:

```
<form action="/example/" method="post">
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit comment" /></p>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about Django. But you can use hidden inputs (input type="hidden") for storing data (timestamp). Hidden inputs are now displayed in the browser, thus making them good for adding data like the timestamp.

Comment: Thnaks Klevis-Is there an easy way to render the value of a form client side to another input area, something alomg the lines of 'get.value'...

Comment: The other input area is in the same page?

Comment: Example-A different page?. I know I have to put path of the page in acvtion, but what do I do to render the value in the recievable page? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to get the data in Python. In PHP you would do something like this: $_POST['name-of-the-input];

Comment: OK-would the preference be render it server side rather than client side using ajax? Thanks

Comment: If it's on another page, I would go for the server side.